# weird ZSH issue (resolving environment variable)

Tags: mac, command-line, zsh

using ZSH mac latest. In .zshrc I have:

```
export ZSH="~/.oh-my-zsh"
```

that directory exists:

```
cd ~/.oh-my-zsh
me@Imac-Retina-2 .oh-my-zsh % ls
CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md  README.md           lib/                oh-my-zsh.sh-SAVED  themes/
CONTRIBUTING.md     cache/              log/                plugins/            tools/
LICENSE.txt         custom/             oh-my-zsh.sh        templates/
```

but trying to resolve $ZSH fails:

```
cd ~
ls $ZSH
ls: ~/.oh-my-zsh: No such file or directory
cd $ZSH
cd: no such file or directory: ~/.oh-my-zsh
```

it's not related to the particular $ZSH variable. For example, I can define export PDQ="~/Downloads" and cd $PDQ fails (no such file or directory), but cd ~/Downloads works just fine.

I have NO CLUE...anyone? ‍♂️

This seems to be only related to the filesystem, other environment vars work and resolve just fine in apps, etc...

Comment: So `zsh` doesn't seem to expand `~` in variables. I'm sure this is a recurring problem, where did you look for solutions already?

Comment: Ok, thanks for the hint, found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56951712/why-is-zsh-not-able-to-read-tilde-from-a-path-in-a-script

Comment: moving ~ out of string quote fixed it, e.g. export $ZSH=~"/.oh-my-zsh" 
Thanks for pointing me in right direction

Answer (score 3):

As explained in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56951712/why-is-zsh-not-able-to-read-tilde-from-a-path-in-a-script `zsh` doesn't expand `~` within double quotes. So you can do one of

```
export ZSH=~"/.oh-my-zsh"
export ZSH="$HOME/.oh-my-zsh"
```

(where the second option also works if there are space characters in your home path), or set

```
set -o magicequalsubst
```

to have `zsh` expand `~` in such cases.